# Embed an iframe within bokeh application

Tags: python, iframe, bokeh

For a bokeh folder application that will only run locally I am trying to display a PDF within an Iframe. The following code is indeed showing an Iframe but unfortunately it is always only filled with the following information: "404: Not Found"

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import Div
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.io import curdoc

div = Div(text="""<iframe src="path/to/pdf.pdf"></iframe>""",
          width=300, height=300)

curdoc().add_root(row(div))
```

Any other solution than displaying the pdf in an Iframe would be welcomed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a folder app with custom templates?

in my_app/

you have :

```
my_app/main.py

my_app/templates/index.html
```

in `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    {{ bokeh_css }}
    {{ bokeh_js }}
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="path/to/pdf.pdf"></iframe>
    {{ plot_div|indent(8) }}
    {{ plot_script|indent(8) }}
  </body>
</html>
```